# Predecessor matrix storing

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms

What is the time complexity of computing betweenness centrality if we are given the shortest path predecessor matrix of a graph?

Predecessor matrix cells look like this:

If node $i$ and node $j$ are directly connected then the value in the cell is $0$;
if node $i$ and node $j$ are not connected then value in the cell is $-1$;
else the cell contains $\operatorname{predecessor}(j)$ (this can be only one predecessor if there is a single shortest path or an array of predecessors if there are more than one shortest paths between $i$ and $j$).

Comment: The following changes should improve your question: providing more information about betweenness centrality (I'm not sure how many people are familiar with it); changing the title as it is misleading; the question is about betweenness centrality; and using latex to write the mathematics.

Comment: @Dave Clarke I just LaTeXed the question, which can be seen after someone approves that changes. (Wow! That was fast :) )